# I have a high pitched squeal that I can't eliminate

Tags: sound

I have a PV20 USB sound board with Berhinger power mains and run a laptop for music. I run a VocoPro UHF-8800 wireless mic setup and have the high pitch sound that isn't constant, it just shows up periodically while singing. It even happens when there's no singing. I can't figure it out. 
Unless I turn the volume wayyyyy down, then pull the main, the sends, and connected them to the monitor sends, it's still there.

Is there anything I can do to make this stop happening? It's a sound system for our church, and it's driving me crazy. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To me, this sounds like a feedback loop. If you have the mains or monitors behind the singers, pointed towards the mics, then some of that signal will be picked up and fed back into the speakers, which then get fed back again. This will result in a soft high pitched tone that gets louder on a seemingly logarithmic scale (slowly ramps up, but gets louder faster and faster) until it plateaus into a very annoying sound.

Usually, you have to then drop the volume down to break the loop (which, I believe, is what you were talking about when you say you drop the volume way down).

To prevent this, try angling mics away from speakers, or angle the speakers away from the mics.

(This is a guess. When you say "periodically shows up" it actually makes me think this answer is wrong. More information could help)

Answer (score 0):

High pitched squeal in my experience can be the result of a cheap phantom power supply.  Now a wireless setup will not need phantom power (it's not sufficient for powering the wireless receiver anyway), so in case you have phantom power switched on, it might be worth turning it off and seeing how you fare.

Next bet is any kind of switching power supply.  Unfortunately those are pretty ubiquitous these days: could be on your equipment, could be a power brick close to them, could even be a LED bulb.

Oh, and standard fare: switch off (not just silent) all mobile phones in vicinity of equipment or cables.